# Oracle SQL query about Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database table named `availableTimeslot` with fields `pk`, `startDate`, `endDate`, e.g.

```
PK   startDate             endDate
1.   2017-03-07 09:00:00   2017-03-07 18:00:00
2.   2017-03-07 18:00:00   2017-03-07 21:00:00
3.   2017-03-08 09:00:00   2017-03-08 18:00:00
```

records starting from 09:00:00 to 18:00:00 indicate it is a morning time slot, while 18:00:00 to 23:00:00 indicating it is a afternoon time slot

storing available timeslot dates (e.g. 2017-03-06, 2017-03-08) which are available for the customer to choose one.

Can I use one query to get exactly 10 available time slots dates starting on the day after the order date?

e.g. if I order a product on 2016-03-07, then the query returns

```
2017-03-08 09:00:00
2017-03-08 18:00:00 
2017-03-09 09:00:00
2017-03-09 18:00:00
2017-03-10 ...
2017-03-11 ...
2017-03-13 ...
```

as 12 is a public holiday and not in the table.

In short, it returns 10 dates (5 days with each day having am and pm sessions)

remark: the available time slot dates are in order, but may not be consecutive

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select available_date
from   ( select available_date, row_number() over (order by available_date) as rn 
         from   your_table
         where  available_date > :order_date
       )
where  rn <= 5;
```

`:order_date` is a bind variable - the date entered by the user/customer through the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want 5 for a single customer?

```
select ts.*
from (select ts.*
      from customer c join
           timeslots ts
           on ts.date > c.orderdate
      where c.customerid = v_customerid
      order by ts.date asc
     ) ts
where rownum <= 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my query only need to cater one table